# I can't get this piece of code to run. It is throwing NumberFormatException

Tags: java

Getting NumberFormatException. What am I doing wrong here ?
I'm trying to read an array of integers separated by spaces. 
Is there any other better way to do the same ? I did a lot of research and most people said that split() is better than StringTokenizer and BufferedReader.

```
public static void main (String args[]) 
    {
    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    Scanner io = new Scanner(System.in);
    int a=io.nextInt();
    String input;

    for(int i=0; i<a; i++)
     {   
         input = io.nextLine();
         int x= input.length();
         String[] splitArr = input.split("\\s+");
         int p[]= new int[x];
         int q=0;
         for (String par : splitArr) {
           p[q++] = Integer.parseInt(par);}

            System.out.println(p);
         }
    }

    }
```

Updated Code, working now:

```
public static void main (String args[]) 
    {
    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    Scanner io = new Scanner(System.in);
    int a=io.nextInt();
    io.nextLine();
    String input;


    for(int i=0; i<a; i++)
     {   
         int x= io.nextInt();    //size of array
         io.nextLine();
         input = io.nextLine();
         String[] splitArr = input.split("\\s+");
         int p[]= new int[x];
         int q=0;
         for (String par : splitArr) {
           p[q++] = Integer.parseInt(par);}
         for(int m=0; m<x; m++)
            System.out.print(p[m]+" ");
         }
    }

    }
```

Comment: The input part you are trying to parse is not an integer.

Comment: @Lemonov How to fix that ? The array of integers user enters will be a string so how to change that ?

Comment: I don't see how we can really help you since we can't see your input string.  Try doing `System.out.println(par)` just before you try to parse it, so that you can see just what string you're getting the error on.  Or look at it in a debugger.

Comment: io.nextInt(); will give you next integers, call it as many times as you need :) or try catching this exception if you still think that one of paramters can still be other than number

Comment: What is the exact text that you  entered when you got this error?

Comment: I removed the outer for loop and after that i entered this- 1 3 5 2 6. The output was-
[I@1f96302

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a `io.nextLine();` (without storing it anywhere) after `int a=io.nextInt();` (just before any string input that you'd want to take).

Something like

```
    Scanner io = new Scanner(System.in);
    int a=io.nextInt();
    io.nextLine();
    String input;
```

Loop through your array to get the values properly; not `System.out.prinltn(p);`

Comment: Yeah this helped! I'm not getting the exception now but the parsed array is throwing some other value.
Input - 1 4 23
Output- [I@1f96302

Comment: Can you tell me what are you getting on printing `input`?

Comment: Suppressing warnings != error handling

Comment: I am not suppressing errors :D It was just what I copied from his code as my solution is not related to that; might as well delete that.

Comment: Fair point ;) I focused to much on this

Comment: "System.out.println(p);"
I think this was the problem. Now I have made another loop to print the array and it is giving proper output.

Comment: Wut? What is that? :D I want the value stored in `input`..just do a sysout of it after `input = io.nextLine();`

Comment: Okay, so that was the problem! I thought you were printing the array properly.

Comment: @AakashVerma It's working now. Thanks :) Check out the updated code in the question and let me know if there is still something wrong. But it is working fine now.

Comment: @HarshitTrehan You're welcome! You can mark my answer as 'accepted' if it did. It'd really help me a lot.

Comment: @AakashVerma I've done that already but I just registered here today so my reputation is less than 15 that's why my votes aren't public :)

Comment: No, I mean to say accepting the answer by clicking on the tick mark present below the down arrow..

Comment: Oh, sorry. Done :)

Comment: Thanks man @HarshitTrehan

Answer (score -1):

Try doing something like this

```
    while(io.hasNext()){ 
        try{
            somevar = io.nextInt()
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException e){
            //just pass through this non int value or do some error handlin
        }
    }
```